# Converting the structure of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Information.pdf
   [1] => Presentation.pdf
   [2] => Brochure.pdf
)
```

I want to convert it into a nested array in the following format using PHP to make it compatible with the CakePHP 2.1.1 email class:

```
Array (  
   [Information.pdf] => Array ( 
        [file] => /files/Information.pdf 
        [mimetype] => application/pdf  
   ) 
   [Presentation.pdf] => Array ( 
        [file] => /files/Presentation.pdf 
        [mimetype] => application/pdf  
   ) 
   [Brochure.pdf] => Array ( 
        [file] => /files/Brochure.pdf 
        [mimetype] => application/pdf  
   ) 
)
```

Any ideas on how to do this? The "mimetype" can be hardcoded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$nested = array();
foreach($flat as $filename) {
    $nested[$filename] = array(
        'file' => '/files/'.$filename,
        'mimetype' => 'application/pdf'
    );
};
```

For mimetype guessing, the [fileinfo extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` to iterate through the array items and use [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to get the mimetype.

```
$temp = array(); //A temporary array to store new array
foreach($array as $filename) { //Supposing $array is your original array
    $file = '/files/'.$filename;
    $temp[$filename] = array(
        'file' => $file,
        'mimetype' => mime_content_type($file)
    );
};
```

Comment: I was just making that response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $newArr[$val] = array(
        "file"      =>  "/files/".$val,
        "mimetype"  =>  "application/pdf"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array('Information.pdf','Presentation.pdf','Brochure.pdf'); //current array
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $val = explode(".",$value);
    $new_arr[$value]=array('file'=>"/files/".$value,'mimetype'=>"application/".$value[1]);
}
?>
```